# Installer for Java, Tomcat, MySQL combination

Tags: mysql, tomcat, java

We have an open source solution with complex installation based on the Java platform.
The JDK, MySQL and Tomcat and the webapp are needed. We run cross platform so we want to use LZPack which is JRE based.
Our software can be find here http://open-modeling.sourceforge.net
It is getting difficult when there is already a JDK and/or MySQL version present.
Does anyone have an install script for this and likes to share it with us. 
Some starting point on LZPack are also welcome.
The MySQL databased must be filled by means of executing SQL files.

John

Comment: Do you really need a Java-based solution?

Comment: @AlexStybaev I think simplifying his application's install process is probably going to be easier than porting to another language...

Comment: We could also use a windows installer and another one for Linux but write once and run on multiple platforms looks as having less maintenance. To make a script using LZPACK takes some time bringing a complete new language.

Answer (score 2):

If your data base is not too large, you can try to use pure java, embedded in process database (sych as hypersonic or apache derby). This will simplify setup of your application significantly.

And if you will use absolute path to YOUR JRE, you will not be affected by already installed JRE

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you suggest that the DB is filled by means of executing java code?

Comment: Yes. We in our company use pure Java Derby DB for medium size user data.